# Cropland field delineation using OpenCV and Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, opencv

I want to follow the methodology in the following article in order to find field boundary delineation automatically: "[Multi-Temporal Crop Type and Field Boundary Classification with Google Earth Engine](https://www.preprints.org/manuscript/202004.0316/v1)".

My goal is to follow this workflow from the article. By the way, the article showed that NDWI temporal images with Sentinel 2 during the crop season increase accuracy to detect field boundary comparing to the Sentinel 2 RGB images with Canny Edge Detection methods in the Google Earth Engine algorithm list. I created Canny sum images during the 2020 crop season and exported the Canny Sum image further to process with OpenCV library in order to find contours of the cropland.
Here is the article's workflow chart:
[image: workflow chart image]

So my question is that how to implement the OpenCV parts.
See also my GEE codes [enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Faidosmakhanov%2Fwork_2021%3AFIELD%20DI)

```
// IDENTIFY Field Boundry WITH SENTINEL-2(10m resolution)

// Function to mask cloud from built-in quality band
// information on cloud
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

// Create image collection of S-2 imagery    
var S2_may = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
               .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-05-31')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .map(maskcloud1)
                          .select('B2', 'B3','B4','B8','B11')
                          .median();
                          
print(S2_may)

var S2_june = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
               .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-06-30')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .map(maskcloud1)
                          .select('B2', 'B3','B4','B8','B11')
                          .median();
var S2_july = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
               .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-07-31')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .map(maskcloud1)
                          .select('B2', 'B3','B4','B8','B11')
                          .median();                         
                          
var S2_august = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
               .filterDate('2020-08-01', '2020-08-31')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .map(maskcloud1)
                          .select('B2', 'B3','B4','B8','B11')
                          .median();  
                          
var S2_september = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
               .filterDate('2020-09-01', '2020-09-30')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .map(maskcloud1)
                          .select('B2', 'B3','B4','B8','B11')
                          .median();  
                                                    
// Vizualizations map
Map.centerObject(roi,10);
var viz = {min:0,max:0.3,bands:"B4,B3,B2"};
var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B11","B8","B4"],"min":334.5,"max":4680.5,"gamma":1}
Map.addLayer(S2_may,imageVisParam,"May");
//Map.addLayer(S2_june,imageVisParam,"June");
Map.addLayer(S2_july,imageVisParam,"July");
//Map.addLayer(S2_august,imageVisParam,"August");
//Map.addLayer(S2_september,imageVisParam,"September");

//Calculation NDWI for every month and define visualization parameters and display.
var ndwi_may = S2_may.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']);
var ndwi_june = S2_june.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']);
var ndwi_july = S2_july.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']);
var ndwi_august = S2_august.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']);
var ndwi_september = S2_september.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']);

//Set Vizualization for NDWI
var colors = ['white','black'];
Map.addLayer(ndwi_may, {palette: colors}, 'NDWI_MAY');
//Map.addLayer(ndwi_june, {palette: colors}, 'NDWI_JUNE');
Map.addLayer(ndwi_july, {palette: colors}, 'NDWI_JULY');
//Map.addLayer(ndwi_august, {palette: colors}, 'NDWI_AUGUST');
//Map.addLayer(ndwi_september, {palette: colors}, 'NDWI_SEPTEMBER');

// Perform Canny edge detection and display the result.
var canny_may = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: ndwi_may, threshold: 0.1, sigma: 1
});
Map.addLayer(canny_may, {}, 'canny_may');

var canny_june = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: ndwi_june, threshold: 0.1, sigma: 1
});
//Map.addLayer(canny_june, {}, 'canny_june');

var canny_july = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: ndwi_july, threshold: 0.1, sigma: 1
});
//Map.addLayer(canny_july, {}, 'canny_july');

var canny_august = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: ndwi_august, threshold: 0.1, sigma: 1
});
//Map.addLayer(canny_august, {}, 'canny_august');

var canny_september = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
  image: ndwi_september, threshold: 0.1, sigma: 1
});
//Map.addLayer(canny_september, {}, 'canny_september');

// Perform Aggregation for canny images

var image_comb = ee.ImageCollection([canny_may, canny_june,canny_july,canny_august, canny_september]);
print(image_comb);

// Compute a sum image and display.
var cannyOverlay = image_comb.sum();
print(cannyOverlay);

Map.addLayer(cannyOverlay.clip(roi), {}, 'cannyOverlay_SUM');


//EXPORT IMAGE into DRIVE
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: cannyOverlay.clip(roi).select('nd'),
  description: 'cannyOverlay_SUM',
  scale: 10,
  region: roi,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  crs:'EPSG:4326'
});
```